# MVC ASP.NET Ajax.ActionLink styling

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a web project where I have multiple button's that are as follows:

```
       @Html.ActionLink("Build", "ViewBuilt",null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "placeholder", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,HttpMethod = "GET"}, new { @class = "button", id= "BuildView" })
```

Everything above works, except I'm looking to add an a font based icon to this. If I were using a normal HTML link, it would look like the following:

```
<a href="#" class="button"><span class="icon-hammer">&nbsp;</span>Build</a>
```

Ajax Link - CUrrent
  [image: Current Ajax Link]

Html Link, what I want my Ajax link to look like
  [image: HTML Link]

Comment: Looks like this could be done with a css background image, otherwise you may need to write a new ActionLink helper.

Comment: Trying to avoid using css sprites for this one if possible. But thanks

Comment: I'd suggest a custom html helper then, similiar to @whoshotjr's answer, but wrapped up into a `@Html` call, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/649394/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-HTML-Helpers-Csharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with Actionlink.

Url.Action may do the trick:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action(....) %>">
<span class="icon-hammer">&nbsp;</span>Build
</a>
```